# Can a second scanner be configured with Brother's Control Center 4 software?

Tags: scanner

I have a multi purpose printer/scanner Brother machine, a MFC-9340CDW installed on  my windows 10 PC. All features were installed and working correctly. But when I added my other Brother scanner, an ADS-2000, suddenly I can only scan with it.

Can the Brother Control Center 4 software support 2 separate, or duplicate scanners and allow users to select between them?  I have the latest firmware and software drivers for both machines downloaded from the Brother’s web site. Advanced Mode on CC4 does not seem to help with this either.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, multiple brother devices are configurable in CC4 at the same time. I would never recommend using Home Mode, it is actually more confusing than Advanced Mode, which is far simpler / more streamlined.

In Advanced mode, there is a drop down at the top that lets you select which device you are scanning to.